# Links to i.stack.imgur.com sometimes become dead

Tags: discussion, images

It seems sometimes imgur.com go dead after a while.

Going through top rated visualization posts [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization?sort=votes) I see that about half of the image links are dead (the posts are 1-4 years old)

For instance:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVgUn.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy3xp.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Fka.png

Is anyone observing this on other stack-exchange sites?

Comment: They're not broken. Our Imgur instance is currently down (throwing 503 errors for me).

Comment: @animuson local file image upload to chat and to the main sites is also borked. See discussion in TL.

Comment: It's happening on SFF:SE.

Comment: @Richard It's happening _everywhere_. The website that hosts the images is down.

Comment: Try now. It should be fixed.

Comment: [tag:status-norepro]. Appears to be fixed now.

Comment: No site got 100% up time, and this includes image hosts as well. 
If imgur images are down for few minutes every few days it's less than 1% of the time which IMO isn't that bad.